# How do you split a Dictionary into another Dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

Considering this dictionary :

```
var dict = ["Steve": 17,
             "Marc": 38,
             "Xavier": 21,
             "Rolf": 45,
             "Peter": 67,
             "Nassim" : 87,
             "Raj": 266,
             "Paul": 220,
             "Bill": 392]
```

I need to create 3 new instances of a Category object:

```
class Category {
    var name = ""
    var note = 0
}
```

And create 3 new instances of this object (i.e: junior, intermediate, senior) with var dict.

Supposing I already know that the first 3 are junior, the next 3 intermediate, and the last 3 are senior.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you construct your source? if it is manually done, then better yet for you to manually divide them.

Comment: It's not clear what do you expect as output. What's `note` in `Category`? And where are the `dict` elements that goes into a category stored?

Comment: the dict come from a JSON initially and the note in Category is the value

Comment: I thought this question sounded familiar. Turns out it was also you who asked this yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208700/create-a-filter-and-display-function-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

In general Dictionary is not ordered so you cannot iterate over it like over Array. But you could do something like this:

```
    let array = [("Steve", 17),
                 ("Marc", 38),
                 ("Xavier", 21),
                 ("Rolf", 45),
                 ("Peter", 67),
                 ("Nassim", 87),
                 ("Raj", 266),
                 ("Paul", 220),
                 ("Bill", 392)]
    var dicts = [[String: Int]]()

    for _ in 0..<3 {
        dicts.append([String: Int]())
    }

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        dicts[i % 3][array[i].0] = array[i].1
    }
```

Comment: But every time you execute the code, you will receive different values in dicts

Comment: you actually **can** iterate over dictionary, but definitely can't guaranty order: `for (key, value) in dictionary {}`

Comment: Like I said, you cannot iterate over it *like* over Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to change the input data ever (homework?) this may be what you want:

```
import Foundation

var data = ["Steve": 17,
             "Marc": 38,
             "Xavier": 21,
             "Rolf": 45,
             "Peter": 67,
             "Nassim" : 87,
             "Raj": 266,
             "Paul": 220,
             "Bill": 392]


enum Seniority { case senior, junior, intermediate }

struct Worker {
    let name: String
    let note: Int
}

struct Category {
    let seniority: Seniority
    let staff: [Worker]
}

/* the partition is fixed, but at least sort by score to get it */
let all = data.sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.value < b.value
}

/* let's use some weird variable names to note the absurd of a hardcoded partition */
let _1_3 = all.prefix(3)
let _4_6 = all.suffix(from: 3).prefix(3)
let _7_9 = all.suffix(3)

let junior = Category(seniority: .junior, staff: _1_3.map { Worker(name: $0.key, note: $0.value) })
let intermediate = Category(seniority: .intermediate, staff: _4_6.map { Worker(name: $0.key, note: $0.value) })
let senior = Category(seniority: .senior, staff: _7_9.map { Worker(name: $0.key, note: $0.value) })
```

Let's check the resulting categories:

```
print(junior.staff.map { "\($0.name) -> \($0.note)" })
// ["Steve -> 17", "Xavier -> 21", "Marc -> 38"]
print(intermediate.staff.map { "\($0.name) -> \($0.note)" })
// ["Rolf -> 45", "Peter -> 67", "Nassim -> 87"]
print(senior.staff.map { "\($0.name) -> \($0.note)" })
// ["Paul -> 220", "Raj -> 266", "Bill -> 392"]
```

---

Original answer:

If the numbers in `dict` (I renamed it to `staff`) are some kind of score:

```
import Foundation

var staff = ["Steve": 17,
            "Marc": 38,
            "Xavier": 21,
            "Rolf": 45,
            "Peter": 67,
            "Nassim" : 87,
            "Raj": 266,
            "Paul": 220,
            "Bill": 392]
```

Let's define a partition on them:

```
let categories: [String:Any] = [
    "junior" : (0...19),
    "intermediate": (20..<100),
    "senior": (100...)
]
```

Plus a function to return the seniority name for a given score based on that partition:

```
func seniority(score: Int) -> String {
    for category in categories {
        if let range = category.value as? CountableRange<Int> {
            if range.contains(score) {
                return category.key
            }
        }
        else if let range = category.value as? CountableClosedRange<Int> {
            if range.contains(score) {
                return category.key
            }
        }
        else if let range = category.value as? CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int> {
            if range.contains(score) {
                return category.key
            }
        }
    }
    fatalError("Defined ranges should cover all possible scores")
}

assert(seniority(score: staff["Steve"]!) == "junior")
assert(seniority(score: staff["Xavier"]!) == "intermediate")
assert(seniority(score: staff["Paul"]!) == "senior")
```

Finally use the partition and the defined function to split the original `staff` dictionary into "n" new dictionaries:

```
var newStaff = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(categories.keys, 
                          repeatElement([String:Int](), count: categories.count)))
for (name, score) in staff {
    let category = seniority(score: score)
    newStaff[category]![name] = score
}

print(newStaff)
```

I got:

```
["intermediate": ["Nassim": 87, "Marc": 38, "Peter": 67, "Rolf": 45, "Xavier": 21], 
 "senior": ["Bill": 392, "Paul": 220, "Raj": 266], 
 "junior": ["Steve": 17]
]
```

You can adapt it easily to your exact needs.

Comment: Thank's but my need is easier. I already know in the order of the dict that the first 3 are junior, the next 3 intermediate, and the last 3 are senior.

I just need to create 3 new instances (junior with the first 3, intermediate with the next 3....)

Answer (score 0):

I probably would define a Worker class like this:

```
enum Seniority {
    case junior, intermediate, senior
}

struct Worker {
    var name: String
    var score: Int
    var seniority: Seniority
}
```

you can then map the dictionary to an array of workers (note that you have to use the names and you cannot use the order since [dictionaries have no order](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) in Swift):

```
var workers = [Worker]()
for name in dict.keys {
    switch name {
    case "Steve", "Marc", "Xavier": workers += [Worker(name: name, score: dict[name]!, seniority: .junior)]
    case "Rolf", "Peter", "Nassim": workers += [Worker(name: name, score: dict[name]!, seniority: .intermediate)]
    default: workers += [Worker(name: name, score: dict[name]!, seniority: .senior)]
    }
}
```

with it you could for example retrieve an array of only senior workers like this:

```
let seniors = workers.filter { $0.seniority == .senior }
```